# Access LAN directory system in PHP

Tags: php, filesystems, cross-platform, lan

I have created a code snippet which work with directory system of a system.

I have created a text box and user enter complete absolute path of a directory and it retrieve all images name from that folder

Its working fine over my File system. Now what I want is:

- How to access other system ( mainly windows ) shared folder (directory ) over LAN

I have enable `allow_furl_open` but when I access as this is a PHP file and other system has no PHP. I am just looking for functional reference which do so.

Comment: is network encrypted or password protected?
check listening the port and ip..

Comment: if you can access the shared folder , you could usually use the path like `//servername/myshare `

Comment: There is no encryption simple LAN simple story. I have installed samba and try `smb://SystemName/SharedFolder` but the it stops with  `is_dir()` scans it wrapped quotes/:(